# Showing loading with Lottie with AsyncTask

Tags: android, loading, lottie

I am supposed to use the Android standard for showing loading in my app. I see this awesome library's in Lottie https://lottiefiles.com/890-loading-animation. Can someone help me understand how to use it in Asynctask in Android and on an overlay in Android?

I was able to do start and stop animation.

Answer (score 0):

You just add this in your app gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:$lottieVersion'
}
```

and include in layout file

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/originalTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/name"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
            app:lottie_loop="true"/>
```

@raw/name is resource file you downloaded from https://lottiefiles.com/890-loading-animation

You can checkout lottie samples on git https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/tree/4ea04fd194649d48b217f91c260735f7d0852187/LottieSample

Answer (score -1):

```
 new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
    /**
     * Before starting background set visibility VISIBLE to Lottie anim.
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO fetch url data do bg process.
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Update visibility GONE to Lottie anim..
     */
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           // NO NEED to use activity.runOnUiThread(), code execute here under UI thread. 

             // Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             final List data = new Gson().fromJson(result);
            // updating listview
            ((ListActivity) activity).updateUI(data);
    }

};
```

}